# Serializar atributo XML y colocar un valor maxLength.Value .NET

Tags: asp.net, xml, serialización, atributos, xml-schema

Cómo puedo colocar el atributo maxLength.Value a las variables de la siguiente clase:

```js
   <System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")>
<System.SerializableAttribute()>
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>
<System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")>
Partial Public Class DT_sapDistrInvMensualResponse
Private nroContratoField As String
Private medioEmiField As String
Private porcInvField As Decimal
Private montoInvField As Decimal

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)> ----> aqui necesito colocar la estructura maxlenght
Public Property nroContrato As String
    Get
        Return Me.nroContratoField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.nroContratoField = value
    End Set
End Property

<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)>
Public Property medioEmi As String
    Get
        Return Me.medioEmiField
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me.medioEmiField = value
    End Set
End Property
```

necesito llegar a tener la siguiente estructura ya cuando serialize la clase

```html
<xs:simpleType name="nroContrato">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```